# Unable to access mongodb charts from another PC in the same network

Tags: mongodb, docker, networking, docker-network, mongodb-charts

I successfully installed mongodb-charts and was able to create a dashboard also.
I did the installation following [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/onprem/installation/#install-charts) tutorial.

As I am using Ubuntu, I access the application using the IP address of the docker0 interface (172.17.0.1).
Now I want to acces to create new dashboards from anhoter PC in te same network, but if I use the IP address of mi PC not work. My question is: 
**How can I configure the Docker than is containing mongo-charts to can access from any PC of the network?**
I did not find in the official documentation how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you may be missing is the bridge networking. You should supply the option `--network bridge` which will use the default bridge networking.

Also make sure that the firewalls are not coming in your way.

Here's the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) on bridge networking.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I read the tutorial but found nothing to help me. regards